# struct issue probably related to codeblocks but I am not sure

Tags: c, struct, codeblocks

While writing a simple program where I had to create structs for saving information about a film and a film director, both of those had the same variables inside but with different names

```
struct Regista
{
char nome[30];
char cognome[30];
int nascita;
int doIexist;
};

typedef struct Regista regista;

struct Film
{
    char titolo[30];
    char reg[30];
    int anno;
    int doIexist;
};
```

I had created an array for both and I wanted to pass those as argument in different functions in order to add elements in those array, and now the question I have: I wrongly wrote this:

```
int insertfilm(film arrayfilm[]);
int insertreg(regista arrayreg[]);
int main(){

//other stuff

film arrayfilm[SIZE];
regista arrayreg[SIZE];

//other stuff

  switch (mainMenuChoice)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            insertfilm(arrayfilm);
            break;

        }
        case 2:
        {
            insertreg(arrayfilm);
            break;
        }
//other stuff
```

it should be noted that i passed an array of struct film while it should expect an array of struct regista in insertreg()

I was expecting that it would report an error of wrong type but instead it went all silent and run it without any problem.

My question is: is this caused by my IDE (codeeblocks) or by the C implementation?

Comment: Probably you need to tell the compiler to report all warnings and errors. Check the documentation on how to that (or maybe someone else here can tell you)

Comment: It wasn't silent, you probably didn't read the warnings? With vanilla Codeblocks/gcc out of the default install and no compiler options set, I get "warning: passing argument 1 of 'insertreg' from incompatible pointer type" as I should.

Comment: look in the compiler output panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcc/mingw compiler that Codeblocks uses by default is lax when it comes to give compiler errors for C language type compatibility violations. If you run it with default settings, you get:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'insertreg' from incompatible pointer type

Now as far as the C language is concerned, the above is sufficient for the compiler to be compliant. C doesn't speak of errors and warnings, only of diagnostic messages.

Your code is not valid C, since two structs are only compatible if they have the same struct tag, if all their members have the same type and if they have the same variable name. You use different struct tags and different variable names both, so they aren't compatible.

Formally, since the types aren't compatible, your code is a "constraint violation of the simple assignment rule" and a compiler must give you a diagnostic message, which it did.

I strongly recommend all beginners to compile with strict standard compliance and maximum warnings though. With gcc this means `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`.  Pedantic errors in particular will block the code from compiling into an executable even though there are C language violations.

In Codeblocks specifically: go Settings -> Compiler, then check the corresponding options there, for example "Enable extra compiler warnings [-Wextra]" to enable `-Wextra`.